# Creating a Windows Service for Windows 8 to use TCP/IP as soon as booted

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-8, windows-runtime

On other windows operating systems, I could create a Windows Service that listens to TCP/IP for any communication (like a PBX for example) through sockets.

But, how would i handle this in Windows 8? Applications can't run there all the time and when Windows 8 Metro starts up, applications for the normal desktop aren't running.

I need this service to start up all the time in any situation as soon as the computer starts up...

I also need http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com an open source project to analyze the network...

What's the best future proof practice in an enterprise environment?

Comment: There will be two kinds of Windows 8.  One that runs on desktops and one that runs on ARM cores with the touch pad form factor that focuses on Metro apps.  The former will support services as always.  I doubt your enterprise will replace all the desktops with pads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any Windows 8 experience on me yet.

Try this: If you make your windows service depend on something like the `computer browser` or could be the `workstation` service. The net connection should be up then.

You have to code this dependency in (no sample on hand).